# apt-get command not found

Tags: apt

I was going to update all the software on a Linux server. I have root access into this server. I tried to type `sudo apt-get update`, I got an error says

```
apt-get: command not found
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux r1web 2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Apr 23 18:13:20 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Please tell me how to fix this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it is not an Ubuntu or other Debian-based distribution? Other distributions use different package management tools. Try `lsb_release -a` instead of `uname` to find distributor information.

Comment: @steeldriver, sorry, here is the system info.`CentOS release 6.4 (Final)`

Answer (score 6):

For your server i.e. CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

`CentOS` uses yum (Yellowdog Updater, Modified)

```
yum update
```

Comment: yum is good. The only thing I don't like about yum is seems like yum doesn't conclude as many as librarys apt-get has. For some specific library, apt-get would work but sometimes yum doesn't have it.

Comment: http://everyday-tech.com/apt-get-on-centos/ Read it if you would like apt to work in CentOS

Comment: The post in above comment does not work, dont waste time on that

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to install apt-get on Ubuntu as it is part of the OS, you must contact your vendor and he must reinstall the Linux server to fix the Ubuntu installation because there is no Ubuntu without apt-get.

Hope your answer was solved.